# Time data does not match format python odoo11

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I have an issue with odoo 11 default "sales channel report".
Trying to generate the report I get the following error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
 11.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 936, in __get__
     value = record.env.cache.get(record, self)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 960, in get
     value = self._data[field][record.id][key] KeyError: <odoo.api.Environment object at 0x061B1C50>



 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
 11.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 647, in _handle_exception
     return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 307,
 in _handle_exception
     raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
 11.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
     raise value   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 689, in dispatch
     result = self._call_function(**self.params)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 339, in
 _call_function
     return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 97, in
 wrapper
     return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 332, in checked_call
     result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 933, in __call__
     return self.method(*args, **kw)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 512, in response_wrap
     response = f(*args, **kw)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 872, in search_read
     return self.do_search_read(model, fields, offset, limit, domain, sort)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
 11.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 894, in do_search_read
     offset=offset or 0, limit=limit or False, order=sort or False)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\models.py", line
 4169, in search_read
     result = records.read(fields)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 2535, in read
     values[name] = field.convert_to_read(record[name], record, use_name_get)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
 11.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 4688, in __getitem__
     return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 940, in
 __get__
     self.determine_value(record)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1051, in determine_value
     self.compute_value(recs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1007, in compute_value
     self._compute_value(records)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 998, in _compute_value
     getattr(records, self.compute)()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\sales_team\models\crm_team.py",
 line 92, in _compute_dashboard_graph
     team.dashboard_graph_data = json.dumps(team._get_graph())   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
 11.0\server\odoo\addons\crm\models\crm_team.py", line 205, in _get_graph
     graph_datas = super(Team, self)._get_graph()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
 11.0\server\odoo\addons\sales_team\models\crm_team.py", line 214, in _get_graph
     graph_data = self._graph_data(start_date, end_date)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
 11.0\server\odoo\addons\pos_sale\models\crm_team.py", line 90, in _graph_data
     result.append({'x_value': fields.Date.to_string((fields.datetime.strptime(data_point.get('date:day'),
 "%d %b %Y"))), 'y_value': data_point.get('price_total')})   File
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\python\lib\_strptime.py", line 565,
 in _strptime_datetime
     tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\python\lib\_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
     (data_string, format)) ValueError: time data '31 Oct 2018' does not match format '%d %b %Y'
```

It seems like a data issue or locale configuration, but this is the only report going in exception and it is not clear how to check data on db (on which entity) any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As of suggestion I would like you to look in following things,

- Use type(fields.Date.to_string((fields.datetime.strptime(data_point.get('date:day')) to know what datatype your are getting & does it match with your field 'x_value' datatype?
- Use like this fields.datetime.strptime(str(date), dayformat).**date()**